# Git pull from same repo through different connections

Tags: git

In short: is there a way I can configure the same origin twice with different ports for a Git repo?
Long: I have a git repo, but I connect to my company network by different ways. Over wifi, my origin address is server:/path-to-repo, but over mobile data connection, the address is server:23/path-to-repo. I need to set up my repo so it can pull/push no matter which way I'm currently connected.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t think that will work.

Comment: not with same origin name, but yes with multiple origin names you can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways to achieve this :

1. if you can handle two distinct remotes : you can do this with two distinct remote :
   `git remote add fromhome ssh://user@server:23/repo`
2. if you access your repo through ssh :
   you can edit your `.ssh/config` (once each time you switch networks) to instruct openssh to use  `Port 22` or `Port 23` when `ssh`-ing to `server` ;
   from your `git` repo, just leave `origin` point to `ssh://user@server/repo` ;
3. you can also create two scripts, which both start a tunnel, listening on one of your local ports (eg : `2222`), and forwarding either to `server:22` or `server:23`. You would have to start the correct tunnel when switching networks ;
   from your `git` repo, you should tell `origin` to point to `ssh://user@localhost:2222/repo`.

Comment: We managed to homogenize the access through different connections so the access were the same in each connection, but  however, the first way seems to be the easiest of them. Thanks for the reply. Much obliged, @legec. Kudos!